# How to read xml using javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to read xml files locally from an html page using javascript without using any local server?

Right now I am able to load xml using `jquery.ajax` function but it only loads xml files from server. What I need to do is to load xml from local file system. when i try to do it I get an error from chrome?

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Simplified.xml.
```

Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Comment: As a general rule, javascript or any other browser language technology, cannot access local files. It would be a huge security hole.

Comment: A question worth asking is - what is that security hole you're talking about? Your email client and many other applications access local files all the time. How is that not a huge security hole?

Comment: serve the file, File API is pretty experimental

Answer (score 0):

You can run a server on your desktop. It is very very simple to set up an http server on almost any platform. They even come on a memorystick

That said,

Using [this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+local+file+system+ajax+site%3Astackoverflow.com) I found [Google Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files disabled for Chrome Beta 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270999/google-chrome-allow-file-access-from-files-disabled-for-chrome-beta-8)
and possibly: [Circumventing Chrome Access-control-allow-origin on the local file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742467/circumventing-chrome-access-control-allow-origin-on-the-local-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using some HTML5 API's. Checkout the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) API. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/eA3b5/1/). Tested in Chrome and Firefox. Does not work as of Safari 5.1.

```
// create a new FileReader object
var reader = new FileReader();
// setup an onload callback. This function
// will be called when the file has been 
// read/loaded in memory.
reader.onload = function(event) {
    console.log(reader.result);
};

// everything is set up. go read some files!
reader.readAsText(someFileInputField.files[0]);
```