# $.ajax function is not reading csv file in chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circumventing Chrome Access-control-allow-origin on the local file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742467/circumventing-chrome-access-control-allow-origin-on-the-local-file-system)

My question is very straight forward, I am using $.ajax function to read a CSV file and the code is working on FF and IE9 but not in Chrome....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "autorating.csv",
        contentType: "text/csv",
        success: function(data) {alert('asdsa');}
     });
});


</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciable...
Thanks

Comment: What does the script console say? Any errors reported?

Comment: also console.log(data) in your success handler and compare between browsers.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/shane/autorating.csv. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Run it on a web-server, (even local) and the error should go away. You seem to be running it directly at the moment.

Comment: but firefox and IE is working and loading csv file successfully...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading local file  without a server. Chrome doesnt allow this.

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752452/1085285) for further read.

Use `--allow-file-access-from-files` as a safer workaround.

[**Reference :: Issue in Chrome**](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787&q=ajax%20local&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS)

Comment: i have shared a link of older stack post.

Answer (score 2):

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///F:/shane/autorating.csv. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` means you are trying to load a local file which is forbidden in chrome. That makes kind of sense as you wouldn't want just any script to go through all you local files.
Besides that, there is a way even though you just need to run it on a HTTP-Server. Check out this [this.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Answer (score -1):

Content-Type must include charset

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Thank you, but still not working...:(

Comment: text/csv is correct .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/393696/1085285