# 302 redirect to a different domain fails silently

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have this peculiar flow.

1. I make an `XMLHttpRequest` to my server
2. My server sends a `302` redirect to a different domain. The server at that domain is `CORS` compliant.
3. The browser possibly follows the `Location`. I don't know what exactly happens here because this request doesn't surface in Chrome's debugging tools.
4. Finally I am left with an awkward looking request/response in chrome debugger.

Has someone been able to achieve response from *cross domain redirection via XMLHttpRequest*, or is it even possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395045/cross-site-xmlhttprequest

Comment: @SanjeevRai that is not entirely related. I know the same origin policy. But the server I am talking to sends the Allow-Cross-Origin-* headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers transparently follows `302` redirects and it doesn't even show up in chrome debugging tools. At the moment there is no way around it. I debugged the http call from `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but can only be solved on the server.

Rather than redirect (return a 302 to the client), you need to make the request from your server to the other website and return its response to the client. Basically pass the incoming stream from the other server back as your data stream.

This avoid any cross-domain security problems.